# get data from TFS in custom web application

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops, tfs-security

I need to extract some data from TFS (Team Foundation Server) and create some excel sheet with data. To automate it, I am writing an application . 
**But problem is:**
How can I get data from TFS? Is there any webservice available for this or I need to parse HTML and then get the data.

Answer (score 2):

No. TFS has broad coverage APIs and came in two flavors: Object Model and REST.

The Object Model is automatically installed when you install Visual Studio / Team Explorer, otherwise you can use the [stand-alone MSI](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3278bfa7-64a7-4a75-b0da-ec4ccb8d21b6). This is a .NET API, but you can also find the Java version in case you need it.
The OM is simple to use for a .Net developer.

The [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/overview) are kind of new and you should study if they satisfy your requirement. Some APIs are supported only on VSO and they miss from TFS on-premise and older versions.