# get list of changesets for a specific Team Project from tfs and store them in oracle database

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql, tfs, changeset

I need to know if there is some web service for TFS which we can consume from inside oracle pl/sql and fetch the list of changesets and store them in database.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ad1d963-a172-47e5-a1eb-bd77c1c58731/programmatically-get-list-of-changesets-for-a-specific-team-project?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Above mentioned URL can give you idea of what I am looking for but point is I will be doing everything in pl/sql only to get this job done.

TFS URL is like tfs.xxx.com

Answer (score 1):

The TFS web service is for internal use; you'll have to use the TFS API.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184160/get-data-from-tfs-in-custom-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFS 2015 you can use the REST API.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx

Comment: My TFS' is version 2012.